# ¿Cómo propagar una excepción de un sevicio Java a mi servicio de Angular?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, microservices

tengo el siguiente servicio que consulta a una base de datos Oracle, mi pregunta es ¿cómo puedo propagar las excepciones que agregué a mi Frontend en Angular? , es decir, si por alguna razon la BD no esta disponible solo se visualizara en mi log de Java, pero como muestro que la bd no esta disponible en Angular, mandando un mensajito, de igual forma si en el rango de fechas que recibo no hay información, ¿cómo lo muestro en mi pantalla?

Servicio Java

```html
@CrossOrigin(origins ="http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
    @RestController
    public class ConsultarValoresController {
        
        @Autowired
        private ConsultarValoresService  consultarValoresService  

        @GetMapping()
        public List<ValoresDTO> listar(@RequestParam (required=false, value="fechaInicio") Integer fechaInicio, 
        @RequestParam (required=false, value="fechaFin") Integer fechaFin) throws Exception{
            List<ValoresDTO> listaValores = new ArrayList<ValoresDTO>();
        try {
            listaValores = consultarValoresService.consultarValores(fechaInicio, fechaFin);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error in  Values ");
            throw e;
        }
        return listaValores;
    }
```

```html
@Service
    public class ConsultarValoresServiceImpl implements ConsultarValoresService{
        @Autowired
        private ConsultarValoresRepository consultarValoresRepository 
        
        @Override
        public List<ValoresDTO> consultarValores(Integer fechaInicio, Integer fechaFin) {
        try {
            Integer ini = fechaInicio;
            Integer fin = fechaFin;
            return consultarValoresRepository.consultarValoresBd(ini, fin);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("An error ocurred looking for Data");
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

```html
 public interface ConsultarValoresRepository  extends JpaRepository<ValoresDto, Integer>{                
        @Query(value="select * from TABLE_VALORES t where t.fechaRegistro between ?1 and ?2", nativeQuery =true)
        List<ValoresDto> consultarValoresBd(Integer fechInicio, Integer fechaFin);
    }
```

Angular
Component.ts

```html
consultarDatos() {
    if (this.valoresForm.valid) {
        this.service.consultarValores(this.inicioFech, this.finFech).subscribe(data=>{
          this.modelConsultarValores=data;
        })
      

    } else {
      Swal.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        text: 'Debes seleccionar ambas fechas'
      })
    }
  }
```

Service.ts

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {ValoresDto} from '../Models/ValoresDTO';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConsultarValoresService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  Url = 'http://localhost:8080/consultarValores';

  
  consultarValores(fechaInicio:any, fechaFin:any){
    return this.http.get<ValoresDTO[]>(this.Url+ `?fechaInicio=${fechaInicio}&fechaFin=${fechaFin}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: No me es muy común encontrarme con problemas de BD offline, generalmente eso pasa en una app de escritorio más que en un servidor. En el servidor el sys admin se encarga de levantar los servicios y a mi paracer no es necesario preocuparse de mostrar este error al usuario. Si en tu caso es necesario, lo que puedes hacer es crear un servicio y dejar un observable conectado con tu backend, donde se este comprobando el estado de la BD y cuando esta falle o se desconecte, te avise. La otra es revisar este servicio en cada operación que hagas en el backend y tirar un error si no esta online.

Comment: Lo común no es propagar el error sino retornar el Código html para un error 500 y un objeto con el error, codigo 400 en caso de validación de datos, otros retornan el Código 200 y en el objeto de repuesta se envía un campo con un código de error y una descripción.